# How to show a Panel when clicking on a button in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, panel

I'm new to Bootstrap.

I want a button which on clicking, shows me the panel I have created in a Drop-up fashion.

```
<div class="row">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="width:150px; margin-left: 50px" data-toggle="collapse" href="#toggle1"> Send for Review </button>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary collapse" id="toggle1">
   <div class="panel-heading">Assign Executive for Review
      <button type="button" class="close" data-target="#id_of_panel" data-dismiss="alert">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="radio">
         <label><input type="radio" name="Executive ID / Name"> Executive ID / Name </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
         <label><input type="radio" name="Executive ID / Name"> Executive ID / Name </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
         <label><input type="radio" name="Executive ID / Name"> Executive ID / Name </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
         <label><input type="radio" name="Executive ID / Name"> Executive ID / Name </label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Something like this..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx5B7.jpg

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are having trouble with? I think you have one additional `div` closing tag. Besides that everything is working just fine. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqddbo82/).

Comment: Thanks DavidDomain.

When I paste the code in a new file, it shows the panel.
But when I paste it in the file I'm working on, it doesn't show the panel.

Any ideas why is this happening..?

Comment: Did you add the **bootstrap.css** and **bootrsrap.js** files to your working file ?

Comment: Thanks @DavidDomain . I forgot to add the bootstrap.js file. Now it works perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Are u looking for something like Modals

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Not Modals.

I want the panel to be displayed above the "Send for Review" Button..